# facebook like button and comments disappeared

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I have "simple facebook connect" plugin on a wordpress blog and have integrated the comments and like button onto my website about a month ago. I noticed today however that neither the like button nor the comments load anymore, the last time I know for sure I saw them was 3 days ago.

I haven't changed anything and it doesn't seem like the site it banned (no reason to, it shows up in my developer page on facebook, and doesn't say this site is blocked).

Here is the code for the like button:

```
<fb:like href="http://extremesnowboardingvideos.com/2011/11/24/video-compilation-of-extreme-snowboarding/" send="false" layout="standard" show_faces="true" width="450" height="65" action="like" colorscheme="light" font="lucida+grande"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Facebook Javascript library to your pages and call `FB.init`

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        if ( FB && FB.init ){
            FB.init( {
                appId: '<your-app-id>', 
                status: true, 
                cookie: true, 
                xfbml: true 
            });
        }
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

Or use plugins such as WordPress Connect - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-connect/

Comment: I'll give that a try. I already use a wordpress plugin, "simple facebook connect". I was wondering what broke it as it worked fine until today. I would prefer to fix it instead of using a new one.

Comment: I figured it out, you were right. For some reason, the facebook javascript sdk wasn't included in the webpage anymore by the wordpress plugin. I don't know why it worked before or what make simple facebook connect break. 

Thanks